# CURDATE() does not work for SQL Server what can I use in replace

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a simple issue I am using PDO with SQL Server I had `CURDATE()` before but that didn't work because SQL Server does not support that. Only MySQL does and I added `GETDATE()` but that is not working also. How would I be able to get the current date. I want the information to show first name order by id and todays date only.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE name='Firstname' And Getdate() ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->execute()
```

This is what I meant

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE name='BOB' And Getdate() ORDER BY id DESC");
 $stmt->execute()
```

The whole query page.

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
    <html>
    
    <head>
    
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    //connects to the database
    require_once("../../db_connect.php");
    
    //prepared statement with PDO to query the database
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE name='Bob' AND Date = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) ORDER BY id DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    
    ?>
    
    <?php //start of the while loop ?>
    <?php while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>
    
 <table border="1">
    
    <br>
    <tr> 
        <th style="width:25px; height: 25px;">ID</th>
        <th style="width:90px; height: 25px;">Name</th>
        <th style="width:40px; height: 25px;">Date</th>
   
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:25px">
    <?php $id = $row['id'];?>
    <?php echo  "<td> <a href='../../update.php?id=$id'>$id</a></td>"?>
        <td style="width:90px; height: 12px;"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td style="width:40px; height: 12px;"><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
  
    </tr>
     
    </table>
    
      <?php } //end of the while loop?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here is the page were user updates the information

```
<?php
    include('db_connect.php');
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id= :id");
    $result->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>


</head>
<body class='body'>
<form action = "update_process.php"  method ="post" class="Form">
        
<p><input type ="hidden" name = "id" value="<?php print($id); ?>"</p>

<table border='1' align="center">
<tr>    
    <td>Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['name']) ?>"name="name"></td>
</tr>

<tr>    
    <td>Date</td>
<td style="width: 303px">
<input type="text" value ="<?php echo date("Y-m-d",time())?>"name="date" style="width: 148px"></td>


</tr>

</table>
    
<input type="submit" value= "Update Information">
<br>
</div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: `cast(getdate() as date`.  But your `where` clause doesn't make sense.  It needs a comparison of some sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent function in SQL Server to match `CURDATE()` from MySQL but you can mimic it by casting `GETDATE()` to `DATE` date type (which strips the time component):

```sql
CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

However, your SQL statement still doesn't make sense, I suspect you mean to compare the date to a column in your table, something like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM students 
WHERE name='Firstname' 
AND SomeDateColumn = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: I'm getting this error The data types text and date are incompatible in the equal to operator. I have my textbox with date auto fill with this <?php echo date("Y-m-d",time())?>

Comment: date goes in like this in the db 2014-11-25

Comment: The date goes in where?

Comment: not sure if that format is correct to pull that date like that.

Comment: That is the preferred format, but where are you using it in your query?

Comment: How would that format read I am looking it up now. I think My database has the date incorrect so it is not matching the Cast(GETDATE()AS Date)

Comment: I posted my whole code at the top I keep getting this error [25-Nov-2014 14:45:27 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The data types text and date are incompatible in the equal to operator.' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\students.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\students.php(16): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\students.php on line 16

Comment: Looks like the `Date` column in the `requests` table isn't a date foramt?

Comment: I think it is because I made my column in the database text

Comment: Thank you got it working had to change from text to nvarchar(50) to do it this way