# Count all the registers by territory_owner per mouth

Tags: sql, sql-server

This time I want to count all the registers that are "Escalado FSM" by territory_owner per mouth. This is the code that I have Registers/creationdate/territory_owner

```
SELECT
CONCAT('MAS-',jis.issuenum) AS 'Register', 
CONVERT(varchar,jis.created,103) AS 'Created_f',
OTS.TERRITORY_OWNER

FROM [DWH].[JIR].[jiraissue] jis
LEFT JOIN [DWH].[JIR].[customfieldvalue] CF1 ON (CF1.issue = jis.id AND CF1.CUSTOMFIELD = 10004) /*Identificador de OT*/
LEFT JOIN dwh.jir.issuestatus iss ON iss.id = jis.issuestatus

OUTER APPLY
(SELECT woo.WORKORDERID,WORKORDERNAME,WORKORDERTYPEID,SELLDATE,woo.CLOSEDATE,woo.CREATEDDATE,woo.LASTMODIFIEDDATE,CLI_ID,ws.WORKORDERSERVICEID,WORKORDERSERVICETYPE,prt.PARTNERCODE,OLTCODE,OLTGPONPORT,OLTMODEL,OLTCARD,CTOCODE,CTODIRECTION,PPAIE,TEMPLATE,GESCAL,TERRITORY_OWNER,TECHNICALCHARACTERISTIC,DOWNSPEED,UPSPEED,REMOTEID,TESAORDERID,TESASUBORDERID,ADMINNUMBER,WORKDATE,VLANS,VLANC,TESAONTID,TESAONTVENDOR,RFSDATE,RFBDATE,LINKSTATE,NMIGA FROM dwh.wo.WO woo 
LEFT JOIN dwh.wo.wo_service ws ON ws.workorderid = woo.workorderid AND WORKORDERSERVICETYPE = 'FTTH'
LEFT JOIN dwh.wo.WO_SERVICE_FTTH wsf ON wsf.WORKORDERSERVICEID = ws.WORKORDERSERVICEID
LEFT JOIN dwh.wo.[PARTNER] prt ON prt.PARTNERID = ws.PARTNERID
WHERE woo.WORKORDERID = CF1.STRINGVALUE) AS OTS

WHERE iss.pname = 'Escalado FSM'
WHERE YEAR(CONVERT(varchar,jis.created,103)) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(CONVERT(varchar,jis.created,103)) BETWEEN 1 and 12
GROUP BY MONTH(CONVERT(varchar,jis.created,103))
ORDER BY 1;
```

But I have an error in the second WHERE, it give me an error message:

> CURDATE is not recognized built-in function name part

Maybe because *Created_f* is not in *date* format?

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks a lot

This is an example of what I want

| mounth | territory owner | count registers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| march | ADAMO01 | 20 |
| march | ADAMO02 | 38 |
| june | ADAMO01 | 22 |
| june | ADAMO02 | 35 |

Comment: 1) Please show any data as formatted text, not as an image. 2) Please show us the error. I can't tell if the data in your picture is sample data or expected results, either way ensure you have both i.e. a [mre] so people can test and confirm a working solution.

Comment: "CURDATE is not recognized built-in function" seems pretty clear. I think you're looking for `GETDATE` or `SYSDATETIME`

Comment: A quick google throughs up the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137398/curdate-does-not-work-for-mssql-what-can-i-use-in-replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advices! I get the solution

```
SELECT
COUNT(jis.issuenum) AS 'Register', 
MONTH(CONVERT(varchar,jis.created,103)) AS 'Created_f',
OTS.TERRITORY_OWNER

FROM [DWH].[JIR].[jiraissue] jis
LEFT JOIN [DWH].[JIR].[customfieldvalue] CF1 ON (CF1.issue = jis.id AND CF1.CUSTOMFIELD = 10004) /*Identificador de OT*/
LEFT JOIN dwh.jir.issuestatus iss ON iss.id = jis.issuestatus

OUTER APPLY
(SELECT woo.WORKORDERID,WORKORDERNAME,WORKORDERTYPEID,SELLDATE,woo.CLOSEDATE,woo.CREATEDDATE,woo.LASTMODIFIEDDATE,CLI_ID,ws.WORKORDERSERVICEID,WORKORDERSERVICETYPE,prt.PARTNERCODE,OLTCODE,OLTGPONPORT,OLTMODEL,OLTCARD,CTOCODE,CTODIRECTION,PPAIE,TEMPLATE,GESCAL,TERRITORY_OWNER,TECHNICALCHARACTERISTIC,DOWNSPEED,UPSPEED,REMOTEID,TESAORDERID,TESASUBORDERID,ADMINNUMBER,WORKDATE,VLANS,VLANC,TESAONTID,TESAONTVENDOR,RFSDATE,RFBDATE,LINKSTATE,NMIGA FROM dwh.wo.WO woo 
LEFT JOIN dwh.wo.wo_service ws ON ws.workorderid = woo.workorderid AND WORKORDERSERVICETYPE = 'FTTH'
LEFT JOIN dwh.wo.WO_SERVICE_FTTH wsf ON wsf.WORKORDERSERVICEID = ws.WORKORDERSERVICEID
LEFT JOIN dwh.wo.[PARTNER] prt ON prt.PARTNERID = ws.PARTNERID
WHERE woo.WORKORDERID = CF1.STRINGVALUE) AS OTS 

WHERE MONTH(CONVERT(varchar,jis.created,103)) BETWEEN 1 and 12 AND iss.pname = 'Escalado FSM'
GROUP BY OTS.TERRITORY_OWNER,MONTH(CONVERT(varchar,jis.created,103)),CONVERT(varchar,jis.created,103)
ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar,jis.created,103);
```